# Rails Ruby array of hashes merged by key to average value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have an activerecord method that finds all events for the week,
 `myevents.map { |x| x.start_date.day => [x.title]}`
(start_date is a datetime field, title is a string)
which gives me an array of hashes;

```
    [{11=>["40"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>[""]}, 
     {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["33"]}, {12=>["9"]}, 
     {11=>["34"]}, {11=>["29"]}, {11=>["8"]}, {11=>["31"]}, 
     {11=>["40"]}, {11=>["34"]}]
```

I want to map the values so I get an array that looks like;

```
[ {11=>[ average of values that occur on the 11th]}, 
  {12=>[average of values that occur on the 12th]} ]
```

but I'm not quite sure how to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do using [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) , [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) and [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) .

```
ar = [  
        {11=>["40"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>[""]},
        {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["33"]}, {12=>["9"]},
        {11=>["34"]}, {11=>["29"]}, {11=>["8"]}, {11=>["31"]}, 
        {11=>["40"]}, {11=>["34"]}
     ]

# first grouping the inner hash keys like on 11,12,etc. In each iteration, 
# {11=>["40"]}, {11=>["0"]} are being passed to the block of `group_by`. Now
# `h.keys.first` gives 11 from `{11=>["40"]}` and 11 from `{11=>["0"]}` likewise.
ary = ar.group_by { |h| h.keys.first }.map do |k,v|
  { k => v.map { |h| h[k][0].to_i }.inject(:+) / v.size } 
end

ary # => [{11=>19}, {12=>9}]
```

Comment: what does 'first' do in 'h.keys.first' ?

Comment: @raphael_turtle First do `p ar.group_by { |h| h.keys.first }`, to see what next `map` block is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:--

```
array = [  
        {11=>["40"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>[""]},
        {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["0"]}, {11=>["33"]}, {12=>["9"]},
        {11=>["34"]}, {11=>["29"]}, {11=>["8"]}, {11=>["31"]}, 
        {11=>["40"]}, {11=>["34"]}
     ]

    array.each_with_object({}) { |hObj, newHash| hObj.each { |k,v| 
         (newHash[k] ||= []) << v.first.to_i } }.collect{|k,v| 
         {k => (v.inject(:+))/v.size}}

=> [{11=>19}, {12=>9}]
```